# gcloud.alpha.genomics.pipelines.run - No such file or directory: 'wdl_pipeline.yaml'

Tags: google-genomics

I am trying to run the GATK best practices pipeline in google cloud and get below error

here's the gcloud command:

```
gcloud alpha genomics pipelines run \
--pipeline-file wdl_pipeline.yaml \
--regions us-central1 \
--inputs-from-file WDL=${GATK_GOOGLE_DIR}/PairedEndSingleSampleWf.gatk4.0.wdl,\
WORKFLOW_INPUTS=${GATK_GOOGLE_DIR}/PairedEndSingleSampleWf.hg38.inputs.json,\
WORKFLOW_OPTIONS=${GATK_GOOGLE_DIR}/PairedEndSingleSampleWf.gatk4.0.options.json \
--env-vars WORKSPACE=${GATK_OUTPUT_DIR}/work,\
OUTPUTS=${GATK_OUTPUT_DIR}/output \
--logging ${GATK_OUTPUT_DIR}/logging/
```

> ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.genomics.pipelines.run) Unable to read file [wdl_pipeline.yaml]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wdl_pipeline.yaml'

Comment: Which part of the error message seems unclear?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]
The WDL Runner repository location had changed. The tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/genomics/docs/tutorials/gatk has been updated.

---

[ORIGINAL]
If you're following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/genomics/docs/tutorials/gatk make sure to do step 4 where you change directories. It is telling you that the wdl file is not in the directory where you are.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Not able to locate the git folder "https://github.com/openwdl/wdl/tree/master/runners/cromwell_on_google.git" which should have the file.

Comment: Looks like that repo has been moved to https://github.com/broadinstitute/wdl-runner

Replace the original git clone ... openwdl with:
git clone https://github.com/broadinstitute/wdl-runner.git

And then in Step 4, change the command to be:
cd wdl-runner/wdl_runner

Will work on updating the tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: @SethuramalingamSundaram If this is resolved now, could you please mark it as fixed